# The usage of "like before"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

In describing a formula I wrote:

> (H + P) **like before** is the time for searching in the lists of the handles and patterns.

I already have explained (H + P) in another case of this formula. So, in a new case I want to refer to that explanation, so I used "like before".

Is it correct and formal? What are other alternatives?

Comment: You would probably not use the definite article there; "... searching through the lists of handles and patterns".

Answer (score 3):

I might use '**as** before' instead:

> (H + P), as before, is the time for searching in the lists of the handles and patterns.

While [usage of 'as before' is declining](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+before%2Cas+before&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20before%3B%2Cc0), it's still the dominant form and sounds more natural to my ears.

[image: Google Ngram comparison of 'as before' and 'like before']